# Flutter bottom and vertical navigation tabs at the same time

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to to create a screen with vertical and bottom navigation tabs using Flutter, i tested 2 approaches:

- the first was to make a bottom and top tabs then rotate the top to make it vertical the result was having the vertical tabs fill the entire screen.
- the second was to use a bottom navigation with the **[vertical_tabs](https://pub.dev/packages/vertical_tabs)** package, in this case i can't navigate using the bottom tabs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do this. I'm not sure if this is the best way but it works. In the bottom, I'm using BottomNavigationBar and for vertical I'm using TabBar (You can choose anything else or your own custom view).

[image]

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  var _bottomBarIndex = 0;
  String title = "Screen 0";
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(initialIndex: 0, length: 3, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      switch (_tabController.index) {
        case 0:
          {
            setState(() {
              title = "Profile";
            });
            break;
          }
        case 1:
          {
            setState(() {
              title = "Done";
            });
            break;
          }
        case 2:
          {
            setState(() {
              title = "DashBoard";
            });
            break;
          }
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          RotatedBox(
            quarterTurns: 1,
            child: TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              tabs: <Widget>[
                getItem(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  text: Text(
                    "Profile",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
                getItem(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.done,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  text: Text(
                    "Done",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
                getItem(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.dashboard,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  text: Text(
                    "Dashboard",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: NewScreen(
              title: title,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _bottomBarIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _bottomBarIndex = index;
            title = "Screen $index";
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add), title: Text('Add')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search), title: Text('Search')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getItem({Icon icon, Text text}) {
    return RotatedBox(
      quarterTurns: -1,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[icon, text],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewScreen({this.title});

  final String title;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: when i select one tab from the vertical tabs then i select one from the bottom, the first one doesn't get unselected! how can i fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to set tab bar items as unselected. At a time, one of them should be set as selected. Either use some different widget or custom widget.
But there is one workaround. When you select from bottom then change the `indicatorColor` of TabBar to white so it will look like unselected.

Comment: okay thank you for making it clear, i still have one more question, can i change the vertical tabs from the left side to the right side of the screen?

Comment: Yes, That's very easy. Just put the `RotatedBox` widget after `Expanded` widget.

Comment: It works, but text and icon blurred on Chrome, on iPhone